# Sort object by property in JObject

Tags: c#, json, list, linq

I have a list defined as:

```
    List<SensorData> tempSensorData = new List<SensorData>();
```

This is how I am populating this list:

```
    tempSensorData.Add(new SensorData
    {
         Data = JObject.Parse(values[r, 4].ToString()),
         SensorGuid = values[r, 2].ToString()
    });
```

This is my definition of SensorData class:

```
public class SensorData
    {
        public JObject Data { get; set; }

        public string SensorGuid { get; set; }
    }
```

There is a property in Data Property called timestamp.  I want my list to be sorted by that value.  How can I do that?
I have tried doing:

```
     tempSensorData.OrderBy(o => o.Data.SelectToken("timestamp"));
```

But it doesn't help

This is the JSON value in Data:

```
{{
  "Record": "A",
  "timestamp": 1572987031,
  "signal_strength": "021",
  "vbatt": "3.10",
  "temperature": "21.5"
}}
```

Comment: are you able to provide a sample json with it as well ?

Comment: @Jawad I updated the question with JSON value of Data property

Comment: You know, that `OrderBy()` does not change the list itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like that

```cs
var result = tempSensorData.OrderBy(o => o.Data["timestamp"].Value<long>());
```

Get a `long` value of `timestamp` property using [`Value<T>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Value__1.htm) method of `JToken`, then use this value in a `Func<TSource,TKey>` key selector in `OrderBy`.

Unlike [`Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.8) method of `List<T>` class, [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8) method returns an `IOrderedEnumerable` as a result instead of changing a source list, so you should assign return value to the variable